# store values from snowflake table into variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i need to get value from snowflake table and store into variable using python.
after that  i need to merge that value with file name(product_yyyymmdd.csv).

below is my code
HA_file_path = ''' select CONFIG_VALUE from CONFIGURATIONS where CONFIG_NAME =\ 'HA''''
-- syntax is correct

file_path = cs.execute(HA_file_path)

its not returning any value and printing something like this :

snowflake.connector.cursor.SnowflakeCursor object at 0x7fefbe68a070

any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line: `file_path = cs.execute(HA_file_path)` you assigned a variable to the cursor object, but you are not fetching results. If you want to store just one value from the table as a variable, you can use `fetchone` method after `execute`:

```
cs.execute(HA_file_path)
file_path = cs.fetchone()[0]

print(file_path)
```